# Type NamingEnumeration is not generic

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

Code sample

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UsersDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Below code I am trying to print jndi data source

```
InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> lst = initContext.list("");
System.out.println("Start");
while(lst.hasMore())
{
System.out.println("List - " + lst.next().getName());
}
System.out.println("End");
```

Error Message

I am getting error message - The type NamingEnumeration is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguements

I have imported below packages for NamingEnumeration

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
```

Comment: What package are you importing for `NamingEnumeration`?

Comment: Please post a valid [mre]. The posted code with the mentioned imports is working fine.

Comment: I have updated the package details and the purpose is for checking the data source from InitialContext method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Enumeration instead of NamingEnumeration and the issue is fixed now.